# getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity CALL -> error : These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using javascript aws cognito

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
                var params = {
                    IdentityPoolId: 'my IdentityPoolId',
                    IdentityId: 'my IdentityId',
                    Logins: { 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': token_access }
                };
                cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
                        console.log('error:', err);
                        console.log('data:', data);
                    }
                );
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity is a backend method, you need to use it from your server, using a IAM user with the permissions to use it (or inside a Lambda method, that will have the permissions to call it)

you want to use in JS: AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params)

and in params.Logins use a valid provider, like Facebook, Twitter, with the token you got back from them.